# Toshiba Laptop doesn't charge whilst the laptop is in use

Tags: battery, charging, led, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba laptop that charges while it is off - it charges normally, the battery LED shows orange (charging) as per normal.

However when the charger is plugged in and laptop is on, the power led is off, it doesnt charge. it says "*Plugged in, not charging*" and battery LED blinks continuously in its orange color.

If the laptop is out of battery and charger is on the power led is on with yellow color (normal).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: not enough juice coming into the laptop when it is on? wall socket? try another wall socket.  You have anything else in between?

Comment: same happens in every wall socket

Answer (score 3):

This is usually caused by the AC adapter not being able to supply enough power to run the laptop AND charge the battery at the same time.  This can happen if you're using a 3rd-party "universal" AC adapter.  It can also happen if your laptop has an extended (high capacity) battery but you didn't purchase the hi-capacity charger with it.

There may also be some BIOS settings related to this as well (e.g. ExpressCharge, RapidCharge, PowerShare, or something similar).

Lastly, this can happen if you have a traveling overseas and using a voltage converter.  All laptop AC adapters can handle both 110V (US) and 240V (Europe and elsewhere) without needing a voltage converter.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that the battery is failing.